# Почему не вызывается конструктор копии?

Tags: c++

Имею такой код

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Unit{
    int a_;
    char* pch_;
    public:
    Unit(){ cout << "Simple constr" << endl;}
    Unit(int r) : a_(r), pch_(new char[100]){ cout << "Constr " << endl;}
    Unit(const Unit& ){ cout << "Constr copy " << endl;}
    ~Unit(){
        delete [] pch_;
        cout << "Destr" << endl;
    }
};

int main(){
    Unit a = 20;
    return 0;
}
```

Вызывается только конструктор с параметром и естественно деструктор.

Почему не так:
1. Вызывается конструктор с параметром: Unit(20).
2. Происходит присваивание в объект который не был создан - это копирование. Вызывается конструктор копирования. Как раз rvalue можно передать по const T&.
3. Деструктор для rvalue.
4. Деструктор для a.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В "классическом" С++ (С++98) ваша инициализация копированием (copy-initialization)

```
Unit a = 20;
```

действительно концептуально означала именно

```
Unit a = Unit(20);
```

с применением конструктора конверсии `Unit::Unit(int)` и затем конструктора копирования `Unit::Unit(const Unit &)`. Однако даже в "классическом" С++ компилятору было разрешено исключать формирование промежуточного временного объекта и оптимизировать код до прямой инициализации (direct-initialization)

```
Unit a(20);
```

т.е. исключать вызов конструктора копирования даже если конструктор копирования обладал побочными эффектами. Эта оптимизация называется *copy elision*. (Даже при выполнении copy elision наличие доступного конструктора копирования все равно требовалось.)

Начиная с С++17 в языке появилась *гарантированная* copy elision, при котором ваша инициализация гарантированно трактуется как

```
Unit a(20);
```

без требования наличия конструктора копирования.

Т.е. в любом случае, ожидать тут обязательного вызова конструктора копирования вы не должны (и не должны были никогда). В "классическом" С++ конструктор копирования тут *мог быть* вызван, но не более того.

---

В вашем конкретном случае инициализация копированием (copy-initialization) ведет себя идентично прямой инициализации (direct-initialization), но в общем случае существенные различия между этими формами инициализации сохраняются и в С++17. Например

```
struct A {
  A(int) {}
};

struct B {
  operator int() const { return 0; }
};

int main()
{
  B b;
  A a1(b);  // Все в порядке
  A a2 = b; // Ошибка
}
```

---

P.S. Никакого "присваивания" тут, конечно, нет и в помине.

Comment: Разобрался, спасибо большое!

Answer (score 5):

Пусть наличие `=` не вводит в вас в заблуждение, форма записи `Unit a = 20;` называется [`copy initialization`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization) она полностью аналогична записи `Unit a(20);`, за тем исключением, что не допускает вызова `explicit` конструктора.

Начиная с C++11 вместо них следует использовать `list initialization` `Unit a{20};`.

Начиная с С++17 добиться вызова конструктора копирования / перемещения при создании временного объекта больше невозможно, т.е.

```
Unit foo(void) { return Unit{Unit{20}}; }

Unit a{Unit{foo()}};
```

Приведет к вызову только одного конструктора.

Comment: Я понимаю что аналогично. Просто речь идет о неявном приведении типов - мы из int получаем объект Unit. Как мы можем получить этот объект не вызвав конструктор?

Comment: @Semerkin Запись `Unit a = 20;` вызывает конструктор. Если объявить конструктор `Unit(int r)` как `explicit`, то такая запись вызовет ошибку.

Comment: О применении explicit я знаю - запрещает приведение типов, в механизме которого я хочу разобраться ( в данном контексте)

Comment: @VTT, а можно кусок стандарта(или другой материал), что начиная с c++17 невозможно вызвать конструктор копии при присваивании временного объекта

Comment: В общем случае утверждение про "полностью аналогична" совершенно не верно. Даже в присутствие гарантированного copy elision разница между copy-initialization и direct-initialization сохраняется и в С++17

Comment: @xperious: Отсутствие вызова конструктора копии в С++17 диктуется правилом 11.6/17.6.3 (http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#17.6.3) и затем за ним 11.6/17.6.1 (http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#17.6.1)

Comment: @AnT Утверждение про "полностью аналогична" полностью верно, перечитайте это предложение еще раз. Фразы про пропадание разницы между copy-initialization и direct-initialization в моем ответе вообще нет.

Comment: @VTT: Из вашей фразы мне не удается однозначно понять, ведете ли вы речь об общей аналогичности или об аналогичности в данном частном случае. Перечитывание еще раз не помогает.

Comment: _«добиться вызова конструктора копирования / перемещения при создании временного объекта больше **невозможно**»_ — на самом деле возможно, если захотеть. Например, вот так: `Unit a{std::move(Unit{foo()})};`

Comment: @ixSci Так результат `move` не является временным объектом (пусть и ссылается на временный объект), оттого и вызов копирующего конструктора.

Comment: *Начиная с C++11 вместо них следует использовать list initialization Unit a{20};* а вот разработчики llvm с вами [не согласны](https://llvm.org/docs/CodingStandards.html#do-not-use-braced-initializer-lists-to-call-a-constructor).

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb У них там своя кухня. А вот [Core Guidlelines рекомендуют использовать именно `{}`](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Res-list). Причем, в отличие от llvm, такой выбор они обосновывают.

Answer (score 4):

Потому что

```
Unit a = 20;
```

это по сути то же, что и

```
Unit a(20);
```

просто другая форма записи. Т.е. вызывается конструктор `Unit(int r)`.

А при выходе из `main` - деструктор.

Comment: Это то же, согласен. Но достигается это неявным приведением типов. Тоесть из объекта типа int мы должны получить объект типа Unit. И только потом производить копирование.

Comment: Из объекта типа int и получается объект типа Unit. С именем `a`.