# Конструктор копирования при инициализации временным объектом

Tags: c++, классы, конструктор-копирования

Ожидалось, что сначала создастся временный объект A(124), затем произойдет вызов конструктора копирования, далее уничтожится временный объект и в конце уничтожится объект a.
Почему происходит по другому?

```
class A
{
public:
    A(int val){cerr << "Constructor" << endl;};
    A(const A &obj) {cerr << "Copy" << endl;};
    ~A() {cerr << "Destructor" << endl;};
};


int main (void)
{
    class A a = A(124);

    return 0;
}
```

Результат:

```
Constructor
Destructor
```

Comment: Это поведение давно разрешено, а с С++17 - требуется. Но поскольку в стандартах я не столь силен и могу немного соврать, особенно в терминологии - то даю это как комментарий, а не как ответ...

Comment: Автор, укажите компилятор, его версию и версию языка, которую используете (если понимаете, что это).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В С++14 и ранее промежуточный временный объект `A(124)` может быть опционально исключен компилятором в рамках оптимизации (т.наз. "copy elision"). Если компилятор решит устранить промежуточный временный объект, то ваша инициализация будет рассматриваться как

```
A a(124);
```

без вызова конструктора копирования.

Т.е. в С++14 и ранее конструктор копирования тут может быть вызван, а может быть и не вызван.

---

Начиная с С++17 ваша инициализация уже впрямую, по определению трактуется именно как как

```
A a(124);
```

т.е. никакого вызова конструктора копирования тут нет и быть не может.

Вопрос сходен с [Почему не вызывается конструктор копии?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/778397/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%B8)

Answer (score 0):

Американцы тоже задавались этим вопросом, и компилятору разрешается не вызывать два раза конструктор.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448501/does-the-compiler-optimize-the-function-parameters-passed-by-value#2448567
Чтобы выполнить copy-constructor вам придётся использовать две переменные.

```
class A a (124);
class A b = a;
```